# Does Saga Pattern able to help to reverse Payouts incase if any Failure occurs?

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing, saga

I am very new to Saga Pattern. I understood that with the help of Saga, we can able to reverse the things if any failure occurs.

Whatever the examples I've seen, they are mostly like **Orders Service -> Payment Service -> Other Service**, and in Payment service, **funds happen from Customer to Merchant**, and incase **if any failure occurs at Other Service**, this payment transaction can be able to reverse **because here funds flowing from Merchant to Customer (in reverse failure process)**

**BUT, my Query is: I have a Reverse scenario like this: Payouts Service -> Customer Service**

In **Payouts Service, funds happen from Merchant to Customer**

Can we able to make Reverse the Transactions for Payouts using Saga in case if any Failure occurs at Customer Service? (**ie., Reverse the funds from Customer to Merchant, incase if any failure occurs)**

Does above possible using Saga? Hope my query is clear. I will be glad if someone could be able to help me on above.

Comment: Looking for an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The saga pattern allows you to coordinate a number of operations an in case there is a failure in one of the steps, it allows you to coordinate the steps to reverse what has been done so far, so you can see it in a way of making all the steps `transactional` without an actual transaction.

But sagas cannot change the nature of each of the steps that you do. Charging a customer is an operation that we can reverse because we can create a compensation action, like returning the funds to the customer. Paying out money to a customer is an operation that we cannot reverse because once the money is in the customer's hands we cannot take it back. Therefore a saga can help you make sure that all the steps have happened or make sure that nothing has happened, but it won't allow you to reverse things that cannot be reversed.

In this case, what you can do is leave the operation that cannot be reversed by the end. For example, discount the money from the Customer wallet (which is an operation on a database you own) and then do the actual payout. If the payout fails, the saga will allow you to reverse the subtraction from the customer's wallet, so no "damage" will have been caused.

---

**Update**: extra information added based on the comment

Sagas are (normally) implemented with messaging. The saga is the orchestrator, it doesn't really do the actual steps. Instead, it sends out commands so other processes perform the steps and receives messages or events with the results of the operations.

Also, note that the steps executed by a saga can have transient failures or unrecoverable/permanent failures. Transient failures can be retried and most likely they'll succeed. Permanent failures won't succeed with retries.

Considering all this, I would solve the problem as follows:

1. Send a command to update the DB and store that the transaction is happening. This locks the funds so, even if the payout hasn't happened yet, you cannot initiate another one and end up paying out too much money. Failures here can be transient (db not available) or permanent (not enough funds). You can retry transient failures until it works and notify for permanent failures. Send a message back to the saga with the result of the operation.
2. If step 1 succeded, send a command to execute the payout. Transient failure: external service not available. Retry up to X times. Permanent: payout data invalid. If the payout cannot happen, the saga will compensate step 1 and free up the funds in the wallet. Send a message back to the saga with the result: either a failure or the response from the external HTTP service.
3. If the payout failed, send a command to rollback step 1. If it succeeded, send a command to confirm the payout and store the response in the DB. Note that here you shouldn't have permanent failures while updating the DB. At most, you can have transient failures (db not available), but retrying should manage to finally update the DB. If even after many retries the operation cannot succeed. You'll need manual intervention and fix the issue, as you can't rollback step 2. You should model your process so that this step is reliable (validations and other things that can cause permanent failures should be caught in step 1 or 2).

I hope that makes sense. You need to make sure to cover all scenarios and that you can send the messages reliably even if the operation failed.

Comment: Hi, at first, many thanks for your reply.. okay, I wanna ask you one thing which I am facing actual problem: Here  I am doing 2 things: DB Update and REST Call (which is a Payout). As you've mentioned, I can do first DB update and then do a REST call, BUT I cannot do like that as DB update depends on REST call (Payout) response. So, what you suggest me in this case?

Comment: Thanks Francesc.. I've read your updated answer and I understood it very well.. I  forgot to mention one more point.. Currently, my application is Monolithic. So I thought to switch it to Microservice,  so that I can fix this Payout issue using Sagas Pattern. But after I've read your answer, I got to understand that there is no use for me to upgrade to Microservice as Payout cannot be resolved in anyway... and I am thinking to keep my Monolithic as it is..Mine is small application, FYI... and I guess I dont need to use Sagas  in my Monolithic and I think Sagas cannot be applied for Monolithic.

Comment: All I can try is making sure DB server is always UP, but how can I guarantee in my code that I will not be going to get any RunTimeException at Step3? I am guessing, any alternative solution would be much better, to resolve Reliability issue.. Any ideas pls..?

Comment: There is no problem in using sagas in a monolithic application, as long as you can run a process that consumes messages from a queue. There is also no need for the db to be up 100% of the time (and it's impossible anyway). Queues allow you to reliably retry if there are transient failures. If you have an exception in step 3, the operation will be retried and if the issue is transient, it will eventually work after one or several retries. I would suggest you to look at the saga examples by NServiceBus, they cover all these scenarios

Comment: Sure, I will definitely look into Saga example for sure..  But I think there is still issue exists.. In my Monolithic app. for Step3, after message got consumed from Message Bus (lets say I use Kafka), after that DB update got failed, then this still an issue, right? I mean, what if I get some RunTimeException, while updating DB at Step3? (ie., after message got consumed from Kafka Broker).. and my Wallet will not be updated, due to failure in my DB Update.. Any solution for this scenario, I am actually got stuck at this point only..

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem because queuing systems have ways of reliably implement retries, so if the db has a transient failure, you can retry the operation after X seconds. A reliable implementation of a saga needs this. I don't know about Kafka, that's a topic for someone else, but check this https://blog.pragmatists.com/retrying-consumer-architecture-in-the-apache-kafka-939ac4cb851a

Comment: I have one silly doubt: So at Step3, after message got consumed from Message Broker, then doing DB Update got failed, then does that message gets rolled back to Message Broker again?  Sorry, if its a dumb query, but i really dont have experience on Message Broker much... and also I searched in google as "Saga Pattern Monolithic ", iam not finding any resources.. FYI, my app using Spring Boot..

Comment: Sorry, there is some confusion,  My DB update depends on Payout Response...At Step2, After Payout success happend, should I need to store Payout response on Message Broker?  I mean, As I am using REST, I get immediate response, so I am thinking I need to store it temporarily somewhere, so that I can use this response for my DB update..

Comment: Yes, you need to store it in the broker. This way you can reliably retry the db update based on the data in the message, independently of the http request of the payout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212560/discussion-between-john-and-francesc-castells).

Comment: Thanks Francesc.. Can you please answer for below 2 queries as well:

1) I have one silly doubt: So at Step3, after message got consumed from Message Broker, then doing DB Update got failed, then does that message gets rolled back to Message Broker again? Sorry, if its a dumb query, but i really dont have experience on Message Broker much... and also I searched in google as "Saga Pattern Monolithic ", iam not finding any resources.. FYI, my app using Spring Boot..

2) I also Heard some terms like CQRS, Event Sourcing .. does these 2 patterns cannot resolve above Transaction issue?

Comment: pls dont think that I am keep asking you queries.. above are the mostly last queries I have, after I got to understand above thing, I will start working on sample Saga and then will implement Saga in my Monolithic app.. and Really many thanks for your help.. :)

Comment: I replied in the chat. Check if that makes sense

Comment: I have replied to your chat.. I am guessing my payout problem would be resolved with your above 3 steps.. I will try and update you..